# PineScript Calling a Current Bar Value

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to run a script for a 20 day high and 10 day low. I want this script to place a dot above/below the bar when the 20day high/low is hit. I have the script figure out besides being able to call the current real value of the bar and not having to use a close value. I want the dots to be displayed in real time when the high or low is hit and not based on a previous days close value.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi. What's your question? Do you have some code to share with us that you would like feedback on?

Comment: My question is how can you call the price at any instance an action occurs instead of having to use the closing or opening price of a candle stick? Here's an image of the scrip im talking about   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oZwA.png

Comment: please post the code you have, and Stack Overflow users will read through it and try to figure out what's going wrong. While this isn't a code-writing service, if you show that you've done some research and made an effort, you're more likely to get useful results. And by the way, welcome to Stack Overflow!